# 1/1) LogicException Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

Tags: php, mamp

i got that Error when was working on site made by laravel 5.4 on server MAMP when i got the error 
the error show in Store function which contain :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'title' => 'required',
      'body'  => 'required',
      'cover_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);
    //Handle the File
    if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
           //Get file name with extension
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
           //Get just file name
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
           //Get just extension
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getOriginalClientExtension();
        //Filename to Store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload the file
        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_image', $fileNameToStore);
    } else{
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }
    //Create Post
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $post->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
    $post->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Post Created');
}
```

the error :

1/1) LogicException

Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)

someone told me here similar problem in the site but i try all solve espactally enabling " extension=php_fileinfo.dll" by removing symicolon ;
it's not working so please help me by findind solve for this problem and thank you in advance

Comment: Did you restart your server after removing the semicolon?

Comment: yes and enven restart the computer to be sure

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP, go to

C:\MAMP\conf\php and open php.ini 
then add "extension=php_fileinfo.dll" manually and everything should work